# how to delete file or Folder from the dropbox using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am try to Delete file or Folder from the dropbox using objective c and also do the replacing file in dropbox using objective c.
I was visit this link https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs but I can not get any solution. I am also used google but i cant find code for Delete folder ,file or replacing file.
can you give some solution. so I can move farther.

this code i was try but i can not get solution. 
can you check this ?

```
-(void)DeleteFile
{
    DBRestClient *dbClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
    [dbClient deletePath:DBdata.path];//DBdata object is DBMetadata for geting path from dropbox
}

-(void)uploadFileToDropBox:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MortgageCalculator.sqlite"];


   [self.restClient uploadFile:@"MortgageCalculator.sqlite" toPath:filePath withParentRev:nil fromPath:path];
}
```

please give Demo for Deleting file, folder and replacing file

thanks

**Solution**
Hey,
I get the solution.
Please Put the this delegate method

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client deletedPath:(NSString *)path
{

}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client deletePathFailedWithError:(NSError*)error
{

}
```

and Put this code your delete Method

```
DBMetadata *metadata = [marrDownloadData objectAtIndex:indexforyourfile];
 [self.restClient deletePath:metadata.path];
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#fileops-delete <- This doc might help you. Please provide your code snippet and logs to point where its failing.

Comment: Thanks for replay
I am edit my questions here i am add my code.this code i was try.

Comment: In my app download file and upload file in dropbox it working find but i can not delete file or folder and replacing file can provide me code ?

Comment: Good to see that you posted the solution. This will help those who come across this post. You can indent the code lines by 4 spaces. Stackoverflow will then correctly recognize it as code snippet. Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) post for more details on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a poor question and should be downvoted, because you didn't provide any examples of things you've already tried.

But in general, for many Restful server API's (including the DropBox one) [you first need to authenticate (i.e. get a token to prove that it's really you)](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/94/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account).

With that token, you'll be able to call the ["`fileops/delete`"](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#fileops-delete) API, which allows one to delete a file or folder.

There's also a [SDK that might encapsulate (or abstract)](https://github.com/dropbox-sdk-mirror/dropbox-sdk-ios) enough of this so deleting and replacing can be a lot easier than trying to figure out JSON & API's.

Comment: In my app download file and upload file in dropbox it working find but i can not delete file or folder and replacing file can provide me code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it using following code:
-(void)deletefile:(DBPath *)filePath
{
    NSError *err=nil;
    BOOL success;


    success=[[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] deletePath:filePath error:&err];
    if(success)
    {
        NSLog(@"deleted");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"deletion error %@",err);
    }

}
You need to use sync API:Check this API documentation for more detail:
```

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBFilesystem.deletePath:error: